# Drupal: Portfolio item without portfolio page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, portfolio

I'm desperately looking for a solution for the following challenge:

The site should contain different sorted promo-boxes (like portfolio preview - with views on Drupal) on different pages. But click should not lead to a portfolio(page) but to a external page. Further on an archive-page all items should be shown and be sortable.

In specific:

Challenge 1:
The archive page should look like this:
http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB02634G3/portfolio.html

Click should lead to external pages. The client wants to insert new items later via Drupal himself...

Challenge 2:
The items have to be sortable - like items 1, 2, 3, 4 on page A), items 5, 6, 7, 8 on page B).

Does anyone know a module or widget for Drupal which can handle that?

Thank you for any hint where to start at.

Best wishes

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a content type called "portfolio item".

Add 2 fields, one for the image (file), and one called link (text). This will contain the link to the external site.

Now you can [create a view](https://drupal.org/project/views) listing all of your portfolio items. Add the link field but exclude it from the view. Then you can use that to turn the image into a link.

There are a variety of modules that enable you to re-order nodes. There is an overview of them all [here](https://drupal.org/node/398508) but [Nodequeue](https://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) is the most popular and looks like it would be suitable for your needs.

Comment: Hi Felix, thank you! That is a real good solution! Got it going :)